# SQL how to convert MM-DD-YYYY string value to date

Tags: sql, date, datetime, hive

I have a datetime variable in string format in the following form:

```
01-04-2020 11:50:44:569
01-03-2020 12:50:44:589
01-03-2020 01:50:44:579
```

How do I extract the date part and select a range of dates?

I tried to use:

```
cast(substring(value,1,10) as date) as date1
date1 between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-05'
```

But it returns 0 records.

However this code worked on datetime string value in the following format:

```
2020-01-03T11:50:24:529Z
```

It will extract the date part and store it as a timestamp and extracts records within the range, but does not work on the first example.

I'm just trying to find a method to convert string value to date value, I have no intention of confusing anyone. As for sample dataset, I think the first part of the question with the 3 records should be enough for testing because all the values under the same variable are all in the same format.

Comment: What is the datatype? You keep saying string but there is no such datatype in sql server. But this begs the question....why are you storing dates as character data instead of using the datatype designed to hold dates?

Comment: that I do not know, I'm just extracting records from a database which has been ported to my server. I have no control over the initial format. It is in String format on dbvisulizer, and I have other columns in varchar and timestamp formats.

Comment: I removed the `hive` tag since this question appears to be targeted for `sql-server`.

Comment: Hi @GMB it seems it is hive. Comment from the OP under the answer from the OP.

Comment: Properly tagging your questions is important. It seems that this isn't a sql server question after all.

Comment: @VBoka: I see... That was ambiguous to say the least! OK I deleted my answer, which was for SQL Server only...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
cast(to_date((FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))) as date) as date1
```

Comment: Is this a solution for sqlserver ?

Comment: the database is on hive/hadoop. So I guess it may not be on sqlserver?

Comment: You have a tag of a SQL-Server and people debating in answers and comments about it. Question before this one it was tagged as PostgreSQL. This is misleading for the people trying to help!

Comment: sorry I will revise it. I'm still trying to get used to different servers...

Comment: Becasuse it was next to the sqlserver tag

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the field is just in datetime format and I believe simply casting as date might do the trick here:

```
cast(value as date) between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-05'
```

I tested it out for a sample string and it seems to work:

```
DECLARE @date char(25)
SET @date = '01-04-2020 11:50:44:569'

select cast(@date as date)
```